# Separate builds and deployments for SAP Commerce and Composable Storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We’ve had the question come up recently about whether or not we can have separate deployments for SAP Commerce and Composable Storefront.

We are thinking that we’d like the ability to perform more frequent builds and deployments of our Composable Storefronts, and right now it seems that we have to more or less live by the same release schedule for the two products.

Is it possible to create separate builds and deployments for SAP Commerce and Composable Storefront?